# Does JPA entity lazy-loading feature cause non-repeatable reads?

Tags: jpa, locking, lazy-loading, consistency

Can JPA entity lazy-loading feature cause the non-repeatable read phenomenom? Can it lead to inconsistencies between a given entity and related entities that are lazy-loaded (e.g @OneToMany)?

Let me illustrate the questions with a (rather convolute) example. Take two JPA entities, 
Department (1) <--> (N) Employee. We want to calculate the salary totals for the company:

```
@Stateless
public class EmployeeManagerImpl implements EmployeeManager {

  public long calculateDepartmentTotals() {
    long total = 0;

    for (Department dept : findAllDepartments()) {  // SELECT all departments
      for (Employee emp : dept.getEmployees()) {    // Lazy-loading of employees
        total += emp.getSalary();
      }
    }
    return total;
  }
}
```

First, we select all departments from the database (at t0). Then, we iterate this collection, and getEmployees() for each department lazily at t1, t2, t3... tn points in time. Now, if some other transaction moves the employee from one department to another between t0 and tn, the employee salary could be summed up twice (or none). So I guess the salary totals could be incorrectly calculated.

Also, if we display, in a web page, the list of employees per department, then we would also have that employee listed twice (or none).

Is my guess correct?

PS: Of course, the above issue could be solved by either using LEFT JOIN FETCH or locking employees in Optimistic Read mode, but I'd like to know about potential consistency issues that can arise with lazy-loading (if any). I searched in the Internet and didn't find any reference.